# Rollback im phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was using phpmyadmin when, by mistake I deleted some rows from a table I didn't wanted to.
I would like to know if anyone could help me recovering those records I deleted. I don't have any backup file and I don't know how to do it. Can it be done without a backup file?
Hoping for a quick answer.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless the changes you made were part of a transaction that you have not committed (in which case you will be able to [ROLLBACK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)), you are out of luck, my friend.

Comment: An ALTER query automatically commits or rolls back (depends on the settings) any ongoing transactions.